# How to implement native advanced ads in Flutter correctly?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, kotlin, dart

I would love to ad native ads into my code in Flutter but I can't deal with it. I'm using this: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob

They say:

Native Ads are presented to users via UI components that are native to the platform. (e.g. A View on Android or a UIView on iOS). Using Flutter widgets to create native ads is NOT supported by this.

Since Native Ads require UI components native to a platform, this feature requires additional setup for Android and iOS

```
package my.app.path;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAd;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.formats.UnifiedNativeAdView;
import io.flutter.plugins.firebaseadmob.FirebaseAdMobPlugin.NativeAdFactory;
import java.util.Map;

class NativeAdFactoryExample implements NativeAdFactory {
  @Override
  public UnifiedNativeAdView createNativeAd(
      UnifiedNativeAd nativeAd, Map<String, Object> customOptions) {
    // Create UnifiedNativeAdView
  }
}
```

And for iOS

```
/* AppDelegate.m */

#import "FLTFirebaseAdMobPlugin.h"

@interface NativeAdFactoryExample : NSObject<FLTNativeAdFactory>
@end

@implementation NativeAdFactoryExample
- (GADUnifiedNativeAdView *)createNativeAd:(GADUnifiedNativeAd *)nativeAd
                             customOptions:(NSDictionary *)customOptions {
  // Create GADUnifiedNativeAdView
}
@end
```

But I can't figure it out how to create "// Create UnifiedNativeAdView"

Could you please give me a solution for Android and IOS?

Comment: This seems to be confusing for me as well. Even if we figure out how to create the UnifiedNativeAdView, I couldn't find anywhere in the documentation about how to place the native ad view inside flutter view hierarchy.

As a last resort, I have picked https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_native_admob, which unofficial plugin to support native ads, with some customizations.

Comment: @MaulikHirani I've used the plugin you had mentioned but I get error: "<Google> To get test ads on this device, set: GADMobileAds.sharedInstance.requestConfiguration.testDeviceIdentifiers = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];"